# Pandas dataframe: resampling time intervals and dividing values proportionally?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, resampling

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| index | start_time | end_time | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 2023-03-11 09:45:27 | 2023-03-11 09:58:39 | 48 |
| bar | 2023-03-11 09:59:00 | 2023-03-11 010:09:00 | 20 |

I'm hoping to split the data by hourly intervals, such that amounts would be:

| interval | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-11 09:00-10:00 | 50 |
| 2023-03-11 10:00-11:00 | 18 |

The logic being:

- 1 minute (=10%) of `bar` falls within the 09:00-10:00 interval, so 10% of `bar`'s amount is added to the 09:00-10:00 interval, for 48 + 20*0.1 = 50
- The remainder of `bar`'s amount (18) is assigned to 10:00-11:00

From what I understand, dataframe's [.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) method is best suited for splitting by intervals, however:

- It seems like resample is intended for individual times, not a start & end time
- There doesn't seem to be a way to proportionally divide times based on intervals

I'm guessing this is a common need when working with time series in Python. Before I go building out something convoluted...is there any built-in/simple way to tackle it?

Comment: Interesting question. There is no built in way that I am aware of. However, in case you also accept "manual" solutions, I'm happy to help

Comment: You can tackle the problem with a series of built-in functions, one of which you already mentioned: `.resample`. What you are looking for is, you want to solve the problem no matter how or solve it with a single built-in function?

Comment: Thanks @hsaltan & @Klops. I ended up rolling my own, with pandas' `.clip` method being particularly useful. Glad to know I didn't miss anything baked-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one convoluted way to answer your interesting question using Pandas [Timestamp.floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html), [Timestamp.ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.ceil.html), and [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "index": ["foo", "bar"],
        "start_time": ["2023-03-11 09:45:27", "2023-03-11 09:59:00"],
        "end_time": ["2023-03-11 09:58:39", "2023-03-11 10:09:00"],
        "amount": [48, 20],
    }
)
for col in ("start_time", "end_time"):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

```py
# Find intervals
df["interval"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [[x["start_time"].floor("H"), x["start_time"].ceil("H")]]
    if (x["end_time"].ceil("H").hour - x["start_time"].floor("H").hour) == 1
    else [
        [x["start_time"].floor("H"), x["end_time"].floor("H")],
        [x["start_time"].ceil("H"), x["end_time"].ceil("H")],
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# Divide values
df["amount"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["amount"]
    if (x["end_time"].ceil("H").hour - x["start_time"].floor("H").hour) == 1
    else [
        int(
            x["amount"]
            * 60
            * (60 - x["start_time"].minute)
            / (x["end_time"] - x["start_time"]).total_seconds()
        ),
        int(
            x["amount"]
            - x["amount"]
            * 60
            * (60 - x["start_time"].minute)
            / (x["end_time"] - x["start_time"]).total_seconds()
        ),
    ],
    axis=1,
)

# Deal with lists of intervals
tmp = df.loc[df["interval"].apply(len) == 2].explode(["interval", "amount"])
other = df.loc[~df.index.isin(tmp.index), :].pipe(
    lambda df_: df_.assign(interval=df_["interval"].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
)
df = pd.concat([other, tmp])

# Compute final values
df = (
    df.assign(interval=df["interval"].apply(tuple))
    .groupby("interval")
    .agg({"amount": sum})
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                                           amount
interval
(2023-03-11 09:00:00, 2023-03-11 10:00:00)     50
(2023-03-11 10:00:00, 2023-03-11 11:00:00)     18
```